# Can't change the MySQL Variable with a simple HTML form

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables, webforms

when I try this code, I get an error like;

```
Warning: mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/content/28/10527728/html/TestSite/page.php on line 20
Warning: mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/content/28/10527728/html/TestSite/page.php on line 20
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in /home/content/28/10527728/html/TestSite/page.php on line 21
Could not update data: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Code:

```
<?php
 ob_start();
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['Username'])){
     header("Location: page.php");
 }    

  if(isset($_POST['update']))
  {
        $Memberid = $_POST['Memberid'];
        $Username = $_POST['Username'];

        $sql = "UPDATE members ".
   "SET Username = $Username ".
   "WHERE Memberid = $Memberid" ;

  mysql_select_db($finalform);
  $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
  if(! $retval )
  {
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  echo "Updated data successfully\n";
  mysql_close($conn);
        }
  else
  {
  ?>
```

The HTML for to edit the Username of the members table, in databse finalform;

```
  <form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
  <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
  <td width="100">Name</td>
  <td><input name="Username" type="text" id="Username"></td>
  </tr>

  <td width="100"> </td>
  <td>
  <input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
  </td>
  </tr>

  </table>
  </form>

  <?php
  } //Curly bracket close from the else from the begining
  ?>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Where is your `mysql_connect`? Also you might want to look into `mysqli_` or `PDO`. `mysql_` is deprecated.

Comment: To expand... The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Please read the section describing the _link_identifier_ parameter [in the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) - you can get away with not calling mysql_connect but only under highly specific conditions that are probably not satisfied in your case.  Once that's done & understood scroll back up and read the big fat red warning about the mysql_ functions being deprecated, ie on their way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) function. You're closing `$conn` so let's use that:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
```

That being said, you should really try to use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or a similar alternative

Comment: It is already included in the header , the error states, when I switch the arguments in side the brackets to the variable names I've declared before.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $conn = mysql_connect( server, username, password );
```

i.e. :

```
  $conn = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'userName', 'yourPassword' );
```

I agree try PDO, for a solution with immediate effect try my solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean PDO? or if you can suggest any other simple way to change the variable of a given **Memberid**, say **Username**, of the **finalform** database, from the **members** table.

Comment: PDO is a new standard preferred by developers and is the most up to date way of interacting databases, take look at this website which shows how to do simple pdo which is what you need: http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2004/may/first-steps-with-pdo/

Comment: That is also initialized in the connect.php